# Weird behavior in Node REPL when pasting text (Windows OS) - Crashes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm sorry if this has already been posted but I have no idea how to search for what I am experiencing.
This be might Windows OS specific I don't know.

I use VS code as my IDE and when testing node code I open the integrated terminal and run node from there. I then copy and paste a lot of my code to run them line by line and do testing etc. I noticed that it would completely lock up node when pasting sometimes. After a painstakingly long time I finally found it only happens when I copied and pasted large amounts of text. IE I could highlight my whole code, copy and paste and it would lock up node. But then if I tried copying only half and executed it then the second half and executed it, it would work.

I thought this was VS code related until recently I did it directly in the node REPL outside of VS code and it crashed there also.

Has anyone else experienced this? I did a google and found some reported bugs ages ago similar to what I'm experiencing but they were meant to be fixed.

To make this even weirder, sometimes I CAN execute the large amount of text under certain conditions. It seems to work if I copy and paste in small batches first, ie split the code into 3 parts and execute them individually, then if I now go back and highlight it all and copy and paste, it executes it fine. But then I load a new node up, copy and paste all code again and it fails. Not really sure what's going on.

EDIT: Here is the code below. If you open the node REPL and paste of this, it will freeze on the first line (so don't worry about the requires not being able to find the modules). NOTE; the code has been changed to take out the IP so IF does execute it will error as I just replaced some keywords with random text. Ignore this, the point of it is to show that it won't copy and paste past the first line, it will freeze. Any help appreciated!

```
//{"_id":"56aba3108d6d183da42403c2"}
//placeholder
const request = require('request');
var mongoose = require ("mongoose");
var lodash = require ("lodash");
var myFuncs = require("./functions");



var item_urls;
var options = {
    json: true
  };

var test = [] ;
function updateDB (){
    var url = "get stuff";


    request(url, options, (error, res, body) =>{
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error)
          };

          if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log("executing cb1");
            item_urls = body.payload.items;
            myFuncs.fixItemIDs (item_urls);
            var primes = item_urls.filter(item => item.item_name.includes("Strun Wraith Set")); 
            for (item in primes) 
            {
                let url = `https://get more stuff/v1/items/${primes[item].url_name}`;
               // console.log (url);
                request(url, options, (error, res, body) =>{
                    if (error) {
                        return console.log(error)
                      };

                      if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {

                          console.log(`Getting item ${url}`);
                          test.push(body.payload.item);
                          myFuncs.fixItemIDs (test);
                      }
                    });

            };  
            console.log ("done");          


          };
    });
}

updateDB();
```

Comment: Please provide an example of code that can be copied and pasted into the REPL to crash it, and tell us what specific version of Node.js you've seen the crash on.

Comment: kindly show the code !!!

Comment: @SaadSohail, the issue came back and it turns out is wasn't tabs so I've pasted the code above. please help

Comment: there is no issue of Node REPL because i have run the same code on my system and it run !!!

Comment: Are you running it on windows?

Comment: @Mucker yes i am running in on window and it is working fine !! try to reinstall node again...

Comment: something really odd is going on then because I have the same issue on my laptop. I'll try updating node to the latest version and post back. I just want to clarify that you are copying and pasting directly into the node console? You are not saving the code as a js file and executing it? Cause the latter does work

Comment: same issue. i just updated to the latest version

Comment: are you run code directly?

Comment: I go to CMD, open it. Then type "node" and wait for REPL. Then I copy the code, then right click the node console. As soon as I do that it starts to paste the text but only pastes the first line and node locks up

Comment: https://streamable.com/ep7wqt Here is what happens

Comment: @Mucker mate!!! there is totally no problem with the code you need to uninstall the node and then reinstall it

Comment: Did you not see the bit where I said I did that lol??

Answer (score 0):

I logged it as a Bug on Github and someone else tested and reproduced the issue. It is now a confirmed bug they are going to look into. It is even present in beta/latest version.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/32999